# New 3DS microSD Management - connecting from Linux

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, linux

Anyone managed to get the "microSD Management" (on the New 3DS) tool to work on anything other than Windows yet?

From Windows I can see my 3DS, and browse the SD card share, but I've yet to be able to connect to it from Linux (which can connect to other Windows shares fine) or my Android Tablet (using ES File Explorer, which again can connect to other Windows shares without issue)

More info, if you've got no idea what I'm talking about:
[Nintendo support site](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14218/~/how-to-use-microsd-management-to-move-files-between-a-new-nintendo-3ds-xl-and-a)

Comment: "What you need: A PC with Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 installed".  It says right there you need Windows.

Comment: Well, yes, but if you ask Microsoft what you need to connect to a Windows share, they'll tell you the same thing.  Fundamentally there should be no reason why any other SMB compatible client shouldn't be able to connect too

Answer (score 1):

I scan ports, microsd management use port 139 (netbios). 
Give a permanent private adress to your 3ds (ex : 192.168.0.2)
Try this adress on your browser windows: smb://192.168.0.2

Or find a apps about netbios accès.

Comment: I've got my router set to allocate static IPs, and have tried what you suggest, but nothing I try seems to find the share.

Answer (score 1):

This has been driving me nuts forever but I finally got it working by manually mounting it from the command line like this:

```
mount -t cifs //<name>/microSD /path/to/mount -o user=<username>,password=<password>,ip=<ipaddress>,servern=<name>
```

Comment: For this to work for me, I needed to add ",vers=1.0" to force using SMB 1.0. Otherwise it would connect for a split second and then say 'Host is down'